# Javascript Regular Expression for multi-line string enclosed in quotes, possibly containing quotes

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to write a javascript regular expression that will match match multi-line strings contained in quotes that possibly also contain quotes.  The final quote will be terminated with a comma.

For example:

`"some text between the quotes including " characters",`

This sting starts with a `"`, ends with `",` and contains `"` characters.

How do I get this to work?

**I guess the real question is How do i match a multi-line string that starts with `"` and ends with `",`??**

Comment: It is impossible to differentiate contained quotes from wrapping quotes. You need to use some kind of escaping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Match many non-`"`, or `"` not followed by `,`:

```
/"((?:[^"]|"(?!,))*)",/
```

or use lazy quantifier:

```
/"([\0-\uffff]*?)",/
```

Comment: @alex: yes, it will, and irrespective of flags, too.

Comment: I think it could be rewritten as `/".*?",/s`

Comment: @Denis: Javascript doesn't have `/s`.

Comment: @Denis `.` won't work because the string has to be multiline.

Comment: @Kenny and morty: http://www.regular-expressions.info/javascript.html -- the js version would apparently be /m

Comment: @Denis: Absolutely wrong. `/m` means `^` and `$` will match at start/end of line instead of start/end of string. It doesn't modify the behavior of `.`. Also in the page you've linked to "*There is indeed no `/s` modifier to make the dot match all characters, including line breaks.*"

Answer (score 3):

Doesn't a simple [match()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) work ? You also need to use the \s\S trick to make the dot include line breaks (actually, that makes it accept every single characters ever):

```
var str = "bla bla \"some text between the quotes \n including \" characters\", bla bla";
var result = str.match(/"([\s\S]+)",/);
if (result == null) {
 // no result was found
} else {
 result = result[1];
 // some text between the quotes
 // including " characters
}
```

Comment: `.` won't work because there could be newlines between the quotes.

Answer (score 1):

Using a regular expression will be really tricky, I would try something like this:

```
var getQuotation = function(s) {
  var i0 = s.indexOf('"')
    , i1 = s.indexOf('",');
  return (i0 && i1) ? s.slice(i0+1, i1) : undefined;
};

var s = "He said, \"this is a test of\n" +
        "the \"emergency broadcast\" system\", obviously.";
getQuotation(s); // => 'this is a test of
                 //     the "emergency broadcast" system'
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback, I would typically agree but this Regex is actually part of a larger regex that needs to be more robust than the solution you proposed.  Upvoted anyways :)